# Java split array into ranges

Tags: java, arrays

Using Java, I want to split an array of `int`s into an array of ranges. For example, the array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

would return

```
[Range(1, 8), Range(100, 103)]
```

because it consists of 1 to 8 and 100 to 103

It would be best if there were a library, but any sort of method of this conversion is fine.

Comment: where is `2` from old array??? if you want random elements from your array then you should write your own method.

Comment: i didn't downvote your question. and how you are pretty sure that i have downvote????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok James, here's your working solution :)

```
private void executeTestCode(){
    int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 101, 102, 103};      
    Range[] ranges = Arrays.stream(getRanges(arr)).filter(r -> r != null).toArray(Range[]::new);        
    String output = Arrays.stream(ranges)
            .map(Range::toString)
            .reduce("[", (dynamicString, stringedRange) -> (dynamicString + stringedRange + ", "));
    output = output.substring(0, output.length()-2) + "]";
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

OUTPUT:
[Range(1, 8), Range(100, 103)]

```
private Range[] getRanges(int[] toBeProcessed){
    Range[] result = new Range[toBeProcessed.length]; //larger array won't be needed
    int startRange = toBeProcessed[0];  
    int ranges = 0;
    for(int a=0; a<toBeProcessed.length; a++){
        try{
            if(toBeProcessed[a] + 1 != toBeProcessed[a+1]){                 
                result[ranges] = new Range(startRange, toBeProcessed[a]);
                startRange = toBeProcessed[a+1];
                ranges++;
            }                   
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            result[ranges] = new Range(startRange, toBeProcessed[toBeProcessed.length-1]);
        }
    }
    return result;      
}
```

CLASS Range:

```
class Range{
    private int start, end;
    public Range(int st, int en){
        start = st;
        end = en;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Range(" +start+ ", " +end+ ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd give this an upvote, but this is almost certainly a homework question.  :-)  For things that look like homework, it's (sometimes) favored to give hints and not the full answer.  That said, good code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(yourArray, inclusiveStartIndex, exclusiveEndIndex);
```

It returns new array.

Comment: Why isn't it what you want?  That seems like what you asked for here, so it's hard to suggest something else until folks know why this doesn't work. :)

Comment: More specifically, arrays in Java are immutable; they can't be changed once created.  (The values in them can, but the array itself - including it's length - is permanent.)  There's not a way to split arrays without at least doing a shallow copy of primatives stored in them.  (If your values were Integer instead of int, a shallow copy could use existing Objects.)